# Wit.ai bot understand wit/number as wit/location

Tags: node.js, machine-learning, wit.ai, wit-ai

What's wrong with Wit.ai ? My bot understand few numbers as location and it breaks my stories. You can see the picture below :
[image]

**What can I Do for that ? Thank you.**

Answer (score 0):

If you earlier have validated some GPS coordinates on your Understanding console, this type of misprediction may be possible. For avoiding that, you can validate some useful numbers with the wit/numbers intent, other GPS coordinates should be validated with the wit/location.

Also you may accidentally validated some numbers using the wit/location entity, feed some numbers with the wit/numbers entity. wit.ai does not know anything about numbers, locations, etc, without you validated them first.. Try to write " Amsterdam " on your Understanding tab, you'll see that wit.ai cannot assign this text to any intent or location entity because you have not trained his modal yet :) Validate it with wit/location. After that he will know..

Also you can train(validate or feed) your own wit.ai NLP without the Understanding tab. You may use simple CURL command and a loop.

Check this out:
https://wit.ai/docs/http/20160526

Have a nice day :)